# How do you store strings in a .txt file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've been creating a program over the past few days. The program stores a string "Dim info As String = Nothing" where the input is asked later.

EG: I input "Hello World!" to the variable 'info', how do I store the value of 'info' (Hello World!) to a .txt file? Or is this not possible?

(Still a beginner to vb.net, looking for simple answers.)

Attempt 1 (Find error please):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim path As String = "C:\VBTextFiles\Test1.txt"
    Dim stringex As String = "Hello world!"
    File.WriteAllText(path, stringex)
End Sub
```

Comment: [`File.WriteAllText(path, input)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [IO.File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) to create a file and write your `info` into it.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) has examples for *Create* and *Append*. Here is a revelant part for *Create*:

```
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 
' This text is added only once to the file. 
If File.Exists(path) = False Then 
  ' Create a file to write to. 
  Dim createText As String = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine
  File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
End If
```

For APPEND, use [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx). See [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx).

Comment: Would I need to have the file created already? Or would it create it for me? And if I just wrote 'MyTest.txt' for the path, it would save it in.....? Or do I have to write the whole path?

Comment: @Meraj99: `WriteAllText` will create the file for you. It should accept any valid path. If you specify a short path, should be saved in [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) (you can check where it points with debugger).

Comment: error BC30451: 'File' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @Meraj99: Try `IO.File` instead. Namespaces should be fully qualified unless you import a part of it on top of your code file.

Comment: Um, I just create a 'Console Win32 Application.' and do the code in the sub part.

Comment: @Meraj99: Yep, just change `File` -> `IO.File`. It does not assume `IO` by default.

Comment: Um, is there a way to APPEND instead?

Comment: @Meraj99: Sure, it's [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx). Please take your time to [study the example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 
' This text is added only once to the file. 
If File.Exists(path) = True Then 
  ' Create a file to write to. 
  Dim createText As String = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine
  File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
End If
```

Change False for True in the line 3 :)

Comment: Is this will be simpler `If File.Exists(path) Then`?